# Trying to Create a Javascript dropdown with Managed Metadata terms

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, javascript, sharepoint-rest-api, term-store

I am trying to use JavaScript and REST to grab terms out of a Term Set and bind them to a Bootstrap select field in the NewForm.aspx for a list.

Thus far I just cannot pull the terms and bind to field. Any ideas?
Thank you
Doug

[image: popup from js]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is my sample test script to get terms by JSOM in SharePoint 2013 for your reference.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    if (myStronglyTypedObj === undefined) {
        var myStronglyTypedObj = {};
    }

    myStronglyTypedObj = {
        // Object Globals
        "g": {},
        // Pre-initialization functions ensure scripts SharePoint dependencies are loaded
        "preinit": function () {
            // Load necessary libraries
            SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.js', 'SP.ClientContext', function () {
                // Register what you need from SharePoint (in this case the term store)
                SP.SOD.registerSod('sp.taxonomy.js', SP.Utilities.Utility.getLayoutsPageUrl('sp.taxonomy.js'));
                // Load the registered items
                SP.SOD.executeFunc('sp.taxonomy.js', 'SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession', myStronglyTypedObj.init());
            });
        },
        // The main Initialization function
        "init": function () {
            /* Check if SP.Taxonomy actually exists yet
             * PLEASE NOTE that it's common that these objects aren't available, even if you've properly loaded them in the "preinit" function.
             * This bit of code checks if the object is available, and if it's not, waits for 200ms and then tries again until this object is loaded
             */
            if (SP.Taxonomy) {
                console.log("SP.Taxonomy ready... continuing scripts...");
                myStronglyTypedObj.therest();
            } else {
                console.log("SP.Taxonomy not ready...  set timeout and try again after 200ms");
                setTimeout(myStronglyTypedObj.init, 200);
            }
        },
        "therest": function () {
            getTerms();
        }
    }

    // Run whatever pre-initialisation checks you need to, and then load "preinit" as the starting point, for instance
    myStronglyTypedObj.preinit();
    function getTerms() {
        var termSetName = "MyTerms";
        var locale = 1033; // your locale. 1033 for English

        var clientContext = SP.ClientContext.get_current();
        var taxonomySession = SP.Taxonomy.TaxonomySession.getTaxonomySession(clientContext);
        var termStore = taxonomySession.getDefaultSiteCollectionTermStore();
        var termSets = termStore.getTermSetsByName(termSetName, locale);
        var termSet = termSets.getByName(termSetName);
        var terms = termSet.getAllTerms();       
        clientContext.load(termSet);        
        clientContext.load(terms, 'Include(Name,Labels)')

        clientContext.executeQueryAsync(
          function () {
              var enumerator = terms.getEnumerator();
              while (enumerator.moveNext()) {
                  var spTerm = enumerator.get_current();                  
                  var labels = spTerm.get_labels();
                  for (var j = 0; j < labels.get_count() ; j++) {
                      var label = labels.getItemAtIndex(j);
                      if (label.get_isDefaultForLanguage()) {  /* Is default label? */
                          alert(label.get_value());
                      }
                  }

  [![enter image description here][1]][1]            }

          }, function (err) {
              alert(err.get_message());
          });
    }
    </script>
```

Comment: Thank you Lee, I will sure give this a try. How would one go about binding the results of getTerms to a dropdown?

Comment: You could use jQuery to add options to dropdown, check this link https://paulund.co.uk/add-and-remove-options-in-select-using-jquery

Comment: Thank you Lee! Works great! the only thing is I cannot get rid of a javascript alert window that shows all the terms one at a time (from your code). I'll add a screen shot above...Thank you Lee

Comment: Lee, added image of pop up alerts

Comment: Never mind Lee I found my answer all is working as expected!

Answer (score 0):

While it appears it is not an officially supported API, this [article](https://medium.com/@ankitgirgas/querying-sharepoint-term-store-with-rest-api-and-im-not-joking-3e158dc31e08) provides the following code to asyncronously retrieve data from the term store via REST:

```
$.ajax({
  url:"https://<your-tenant>.sharepoint.com/_vti_bin/TaxonomyInternalService.json/GetChildTermsInTermSetWithPaging",
  type:"POST",
  headers: {
    "accept":"application/json;odata.metadata=minimal",
    "content-type": "application/json;charset=utf-8",
    "odata-version":"4.0",
    "X-RequestDigest": $("#__REQUESTDIGEST").val()
  },
  data:JSON.stringify({
    lcid: 1033,
    sspId: "guid-here", //Term store ID
    guid: "guid-here", //Term set ID
    includeDeprecated: false,
    pageLimit: 1000,
    pagingForward: false,
    includeCurrentChild: false,
    currentChildId: "00000000–0000–0000–0000–000000000000",
    webId: "00000000–0000–0000–0000–000000000000",
    listId: "00000000–0000–0000–0000–000000000000"
  }),
  success:function(data){
    console.log("Rejoice, for now you can use REST",data);
  }
});
```

Comment: Thank you for this. I will try and see if this works on-premises and to bind to a drop down list.